# How to solve this with the help of pythagoras theorem?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Plz help me with this Question 11  solve this with Pythagorean Theorem. Thanks

Comment: Area of equilateral triangle with side length $s$ is $\frac{s^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$. Can you solve it from here?

Comment: For the other problem, try using area.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained instead of asking people to click through.

Comment: This site was not allowing me to upload a image

Comment: With area we can get the answer but can’t we use pythagoras theorem

Comment: Just checking: You are referring to question 9, right? I think it doesn't have anything to do with the drawn triangles in the picture. Also, I agree with Aiden: there's not simpler way to solve the problem than that. You don't need Pythagoras (unless you really want to derive/prove the formula).

Comment: I am referring for question 11

Comment: Is question 11 referred to the figure which you circled?

Comment: Do you *have* to use the pythagorean theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 11:

Notice x is the height of the triangle.
The area of the triangle can be calculated in 2 ways:

$$S = \frac{12 \cdot 3}{2} = 18$$

and

$$S = \frac{7 \cdot x}{2}$$

Therefore:

$$ \frac{7 \cdot x}{2} = 18 $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{36}{7}$$

Comment: Thanks man i knew this method but i wanted to solve this with pythagoras theorem thanks for your help man

Answer (score 0):

Notice the figure in question 11 has $4$ different right triangles in it:

1) has sides $a,3$ and hypotenuse $7$

2) has sides $12-a, 3$ and hypotenuse $b$

3) has sides $c, x$ and hypotenuse $b$.

And the 4) has sides $x, 7 + c$ and hypotenuse $12$

That's four equations and four unknowns.  That should be enough to solve for $x$.

....

BUt as Kien PS points out it is easier (and cleverer) to note:

$A = \frac 12*3*12 = \frac 12*x*7$.

Comment: Hey man but how to find c that is the main question

Comment: Four equations.  Four unknowns.

Comment: Can you do the complete math for me i would really appreciate

Comment: Don’t worry bro i got the answer

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: If it is Q9 then this diagram should help you work out $h$ using Pythagoras and hence the area.
[image]

Comment: I am asking about question 11